# Firebase Cloud Messaging topic is ignored, all users keep getting the notification

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

### **TL;DR**

I subscribed to a FCM topic, then unsubscribed to it, and my test device keeps receiving the notifications targetting this topic

### **Some details**

1. From my testing app, I called `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("beta")` to subscribe to a topic called *"beta"*, and after a few hours I found it in the Firebase Console. **So far so good**.
2. After that, I unsubscribed to that topic (by calling the `unsubscribeToTopic()` method), and the callback was called with a success. To be sure, I also checked that the unsubscription was saved by calling this url with the appropriate token and `Authorization` header :

   [https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/{MY_TOKEN}?details=true](https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/%7BMY_TOKEN%7D?details=true)

   As a result, I didn't got any topic in the json response. So... **So far so good** !
3. Then, in the Firebase Console, I created a new notification specifying this *"beta"*  *(see screenshot below)* and clicked on the *"Send test message"* button (specifying my test device token).

**My problem is : I keep receiving this test notification on my test device while I previously unsubscribed to that topic !**
What am I doing wrong, any ideas ?

I also tried to target an unexisting topic in the Firebase Console, and I still receive the notification in my test app.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found out what's happening : **The test button doesn't take the topic in consideration**. So the solution is simple : just publish the notification and try in real life, it will work !